# Basis in a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a linear map $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is the basis of $V$. Does that necessary mean $(Tv_1,\cdots,Tv_n)$ is the basis for $W$?

Comment: No.  What if $T$ is the zero map?

Comment: For another example, let $T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the inclusion $T(x) = (x,0)$.  There's no way the single basis vector for the domain will ever create a basis for your 2-dimensional codomain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 4):

No. Suppose that  $T$ is the null map. Then your set is just the null vector and therefore it is not a basis.

Answer (score 1):

No, as others have already pointed out. However, if $T:V\rightarrow W$ is injective and $\{v_i\}$ are linearly independent, then $\{T(v_i)\}$ are also linearly independent. If $T$ is also surjective (hence invertible) and $\{v_i\} $ is a basis of $V$ then $\{T(v_i)\}$ is a basis of $W$.

You write *the* basis of a vector space, but a generic vector space has no preferred basis, and there always are many possible bases (a very simple way to generate new bases from a given one is to change the sign of some basis elements, but you can do much more than that). Therefore, it would be better to write (and think) of *a* basis.